# Does Azure IOT replace IIS?

Tags: azure, iis, azure-iot-hub

I didnt have any idea what Azure IOT is. My manager told me that IOT is a new thing and we can replace IIS with Azure IOT but I couldnt find any such information. According to many articles I read and as per my understanding, IOT is used for duplex communication between the devices and services in a cloud environment.

Can anyone explain about Azure IOT nicely? Does it replace IIS? We want to move our product from normal servers to Azure Cloud servers. Do we still need IIS or IOT is there to replace it?

Comment: Have you read up on Azure IoT?  I haven't (yet), but my immediate instinct is that they cover two different use cases.  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/overview/iot/

Comment: Vanilla IIS might be replaced by Azure Stack or Azure App Service, but I don't think Azure IoT is the one. Talk to your manager directly and ask why he/she said so, as there might be some misunderstanding.

Comment: How are you using IIS?

Comment: For Web Api Deployment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As always, it depends. If your current website is a gateway to communicate with IoT devices (IoT stands for Internet of Things, think temperate sensors, light sensors or more advanced devices) then it could. Otherwise I really doubt it.

[Azure IoT](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/overview/iot/) is a managed service that allows device provisioning, device to cloud and cloud to device communication. It does not allow for hosting user interfaces like IIS does.

The most probable thing to do is to move to [Azure Web Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/web/), which is basically IIS as a service. (There is a lot more to it obviously!)

And you definitely need to talk to your manager. Hearing the latest buzz words without knowing enough to be able to place them in your context can do a lot of harm.